# Change Color from "Large" UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I'm facing a problem with a "Preferred Large Title" UINavigationBar.

I use in UINavigationController in ViewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

But for iPhoneX I see the view's background colors on TopBar! I will set the yellow color complete to the top.

[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVgFZ.png)

Comment: Use `barTintColor` or `backgroundImage`.

Comment: Thanks Sulthan. barTintColor works well:

self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];